# On Claims based security the roles can be stored on User or on Object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity

In a claim-based authentication can Roles reside on the Object instead of the AspNetUser entity in Identity on .Net Core ?

Imagine I would like to implement the Claims-based authentication and I have the scenario like below:

[image]

Each entity has always the One-To-Many relation with the entity on the right. One Institution can have many Courses, each Course can have many Subjects, each Subject can have many Syllabus, etc...

There are 3 Roles: Administrator, Contributor, Viewer

If you have a Role in one of the top entities this role will be propagated to the rest bellow. E.g: If you are an Administrator of Course you are administrator of Subject, Syllabus, etc...

Initially it was implemented in a way where Course has CourseRoles, CourseRoles has records with UserId and RoleId.
Subject has SubjectRoles, and so on...

**Is it in accordance with Claims-base authentication?**

I just firgured out there is something wrong when I tried to use Policy and this situation happened in here: [Adding .Net Core Policy with variable Parameters on Requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58859199/adding-net-core-policy-with-variable-parameters-on-requirements)

Comment: This seems somewhat similar to an issue I had a while back, checking for a Role that depends on a specific entity being accessed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48386853/asp-net-core-identity-authorization-using-parameter-for-team-membership

Comment: @Valuator I think the the best design practice for claim authorizathion is to maintain everything that is user related concentrated on the AspNetUser table.  I can see appart from the answer for your question (retrieving from authContext.RouteData.Values. Also I see another solution if I would maintain the same design and use Resource Based Authentication https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-3.0 . The main problem is that I already started with a bad design, having the roles attached to the Objects.

Comment: The explanation I see why it should be stored on AspNetUser when using Claims based authentication is that in this case user "claims" some attribute that he has, so that Roles properties should be concentrated in the user, I don't know if it makes sense, but I can't find examples like mine on the internet. I usually can find simple examples.