# "context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext" returning null in ASP.NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to implement a custom authorization requirement following a tutorial. It seems like 
`context.Resource` no longer contains `AuthorizationFilterContext` and as a result:

```
var authFilterContext = context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext;
```

returns `null` and the rest of the logic fails. I am also not able to get the query string value because it is null.
The following is the code:

```
public class CanEditOnlyOtherAdminRolesAndClaimsHandler :
   AuthorizationHandler<ManageAdminRolesAndClaimsRequirement>
    {
        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
       ManageAdminRolesAndClaimsRequirement requirement)
        {
            var authFilterContext = context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext;
            if (authFilterContext == null)
            {
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }

            string loggedInAdminId =
                context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

            string adminIdBeingEdited = authFilterContext.HttpContext.Request.Query["userId"];

            if (context.User.IsInRole("Admin") &&
                context.User.HasClaim(claim => claim.Type == "Edit Role" && claim.Value == "true") &&
                adminIdBeingEdited.ToLower() != loggedInAdminId.ToLower())
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

How should I fix this problem in ASP.NET Core 3.0?

Comment: Have you read this? It talks about resource-based authorization: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-3.1#write-a-resource-based-handler

Comment: I don't think that page can solve my problem. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Actually, I may have misunderstood your question. Sorry. This answer to a similar question may be what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57488678/12431728 The answer is specifically for .Net Core 3.0.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is due to the new endpoint routing in .NET Core 3.0.

To quote the below ticket.

> This is because when using endpoint routing in ASP.NET Core 3.0:
>
> Mvc will no longer add AuthorizeFilter to ActionDescriptor and
>   ResourceInvoker will not call AuthorizeAsync()
>   https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/90ab2cb965aeb8ada13bc4b936b3735ca8dd28df/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ApplicationModels/AuthorizationApplicationModelProvider.cs#L40
>
> Mvc will add all Filter as metadata to endpoint.Metadata
>   https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/5561338cfecac5ca4b1dda2f09a7f66153d0b5fe/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Routing/ActionEndpointFactory.cs#L348
>
> instead by AuthorizationMiddleware call the AuthorizeAsync() and
>   resouorce is Endpoint
>   https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/5561338cfecac5ca4b1dda2f09a7f66153d0b5fe/src/Security/Authorization/Policy/src/AuthorizationMiddleware.cs#L63

New method.

```
protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, CookieOrTokenAuthorizationRequirement requirement)
{
    if (context.Resource is Endpoint endpoint)
    {
        if (endpoint.Metadata.OfType<IFilterMetadata>().Any(filter => filter is MyFilter))
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/11075

It's worth noting too that using the new context you won't be able to access route data as you were before with the AuthorizationFilterContext. You will need to inject an IHttpContextAccessor into the AuthorizationHandler.

```
// Ensure your handler is registered as scoped
services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, InvestorRequirementHandler>();


public class InvestorRequirementHandler : AuthorizationHandler<InvestorRequirement>
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public InvestorRequirementHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, InvestorRequirement requirement)
    {
        var tenant = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetRouteData().Values[ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.TenantCodeKey].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems this no longer works for dotnet 5.0. The `context.Resource` is now of type `DefaultHttpContext`. Any idea how to get the current Endpoint from there?

Comment: @Robba `DefaultHttpContext` contains a `GetEndPoint()` extension method

Comment: @CyrilDurand some further investigation reveiled this indeed. Still a bit odd that doing this for .net core 2.0, 3.0 and 5.0 requires three different casts of the `context.Resource`

Comment: For .net 5, context.Resource is Endpoint is alaways null, 
Someone may use (context.Resource is Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpContext httpContext) and then httpContext.GetEndpoint()

Answer (score 6):

```
public class CanEditOnlyOtherAdminRolesAndClaimsHandler :
            AuthorizationHandler<ManageAdminRolesAndClaimsRequirement>
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;
    public CanEditOnlyOtherAdminRolesAndClaimsHandler(
            IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;    
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
            ManageAdminRolesAndClaimsRequirement requirement)
    {

        var loggedInAdminId = context.User.Claims
            .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value.ToString();

        var adminIdBeingEdited = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext
            .Request.Query["userId"].ToString();

        if (context.User.IsInRole("Admin")
             && context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "Edit Role" && c.Value == "true")
             && adminIdBeingEdited.ToLower() != loggedInAdminId.ToLower())
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class CanEditOnlyOtherAdminRolesAndClaimsHandler :
   AuthorizationHandler<ManageAdminRolesAndClaimsRequirement>
    {
       private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

       public CanEditOnlyOtherAdminRolesAndClaimsHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
       {
            this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContextAccessor));
       }

       protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
       ManageAdminRolesAndClaimsRequirement requirement)
        {
            if (context.User == null || !context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                context.Fail();
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }

            string loggedInAdminId =
                context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

            string adminIdBeingEdited = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Query["userId"].ToString();

            if (context.User.IsInRole("Admin") &&
            context.User.HasClaim(claim => claim.Type == "Edit Role" && claim.Value == "true") &&
            adminIdBeingEdited.ToLower() != loggedInUserId.ToLower())
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

Then add the following services to `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup` class:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {           
          services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
             options.AddPolicy("ManageRolesPolicy", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new ManageAdminRolesAndClaimsRequirement()));
            }

          services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, CanEditOnlyOtherAdminRolesAndClaimsHandler>();       
      }
```

> **If you want to handle a multiple custom authorization for a requirement:**

in `CanEditOnlyOtherAdminRolesAndClaimsHandler` class you check if the user is in `Admin` role and has `Edit Role` claim. Let's suppose that you require that the user must to be in `Super Admin` role, in this scenario, you can either:

*- edit the condition in `CanEditOnlyOtherAdminRolesAndClaimsHandler` class to be as a following:*

```
if (context.User.IsInRole("Admin") &&
                context.User.HasClaim(claim => claim.Type == "Edit Role" && claim.Value == "true") &&
                adminIdBeingEdited.ToLower() != loggedInUserId.ToLower() || 
                context.User.IsInRole("Super Admin") && adminIdBeingEdited.ToLower() != loggedInUserId.ToLower())
                {
                    context.Succeed(requirement);
                }
```

*- or customize another authorization handler for the new requirement which in this case is `Super Admin` role:*

Create a new class and name it `ManageRolesAndClaimsSuperAdminHandler`, the implementation of this class should be as follows

```
public class ManageRolesAndClaimsSuperAdminHandler : AuthorizationHandler<ManageAdminRolesAndClaimsRequirement>
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

        public ManageUsersRolesSuperAdminHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContextAccessor));
        }

        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, ManageAdminRolesAndClaimsRequirement  requirement)
        {
        if (context.User == null || !context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                context.Fail();
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }

            string loggedInAdminId = context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

            string adminIdBeingEdited = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Query["userId"].ToString();

            if (context.User.IsInRole("Super Admin") && adminIdBeingEdited.ToLower() != loggedInUserId.ToLower())
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

Now register the new handler in `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup` class

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
      {        
          services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
             options.AddPolicy("ManageRolesPolicy", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new ManageAdminRolesAndClaimsRequirement()));
            }

          services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, CanEditOnlyOtherAdminRolesAndClaimsHandler>();
          services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, ManageRolesAndClaimsSuperAdminHandler>();
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Changes in startup.cs if you are using Rout attribute in controllers
You can replace this

```
  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
               name: "home",
               pattern: "{controller=Home}");
        });
```

with this in Configure()

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "home",
                template: "{controller=Home}");
        });
```

and disable endpoint routing with this in ConfigureSevices()

```
   services.AddMvc().AddMvcOptions(mvcopt=> { mvcopt.EnableEndpointRouting = false;});
```

Works in Asp .Net Core 5 as well

Comment: Is there any way to use with "app.UseEndpoints"

Answer (score 0):

```
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;
    public CanEditOnlyOtherAdminRolesAndClaimsHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContextAccessor));

    }
```

Comment: Please provide explanation how your solution works.

Answer (score 0):

The Resource property will only be an AuthorizationFilterContext in the context of an [Authorize] attribute.