# Token can't store in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, token, access-token

I have a project using .NET core version 3.1 and I'm using token for logging in. Everything works perfectly when testing with Postman, it created token and I can use it to access the Home page.

The problem is, when I started testing on client side, it doesn't work. I debugged and saw after logging in, the token is generated but I can't access the `HomeController` because of `[Authorize]` attribute.

This is my code to generate token:

```
public async Task<HttpResponse<LoginResult>> GetTokenAsync(LoginRequest loginInfo)
{
    var audience = await _audiences.FindAsync(a => a.Id == loginInfo.ClientId);
    string message = string.Empty;

    if (audience != null)
    {
        bool audienceIsValid = _jwtProvider.ValidateAudience(audience.Issuer
                    , audience.SecretKey
                    , ref message);

        if (audienceIsValid)
            return await GenerateToken(loginInfo);
        else
            message = ErrorMessages.Login_AudienceInvalid;
    }
    else
        message = string.Format(ErrorMessages.Login_Not_Permitted, "Your client Id");
    return HttpResponse<LoginResult>.Error(message, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
```

I guess that token couldn't be stored correctly.

What am I missing?

UPDATE
This is my code in login

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("login")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login([FromForm]LoginRequest model)
{
      model.ClientId = 1;
      var response = await _services.GetTokenAsync(model);
      if (response.StatusCode == 200)
      {
           return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
      }
      return RedirectToAction("Login");
}
```

And this is what I'm trying to access

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("index")]
[Authorize]
public IActionResult Index()
{
     return View();
}
```

Comment: None of the code provided helps identify why the token is stored properly. Are you passing it correctly to the back end?

Comment: seems that you have shown server code to generate the token. However how do you store it on the client side? You have to get the token and provide it for each service call like the Postman test does

Comment: @oleksa seems like i didn't get the token and send it to anywhere so I can't be stored and I can't use it. Do you have any direction for this? I'm just a new member to .NET core so I don't know how to provide token to every functions which need it. Thank you.

Comment: @Mickers I don't know whether or not I passed it to the back end, maybe not, do you have any directions for that, I really don't know how to do it, thank you.

Comment: Typically you store the token in session or local storage on the front end then you pass it on each subsequent API call in the headers like `token ${token}`.

Comment: @Mickers yes I think that's my problem, I'm trying to store the token in the header but it still doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom policy to specify in the Authorize attribute that is configured to use a custom requirement handler

First you lay out the requirement of the custom policy via a class that inherits `IAuthorizationRequirement`

```
public class TokenRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
}
```

This is where you would optionally accept parameters if you need them. But normally you pass a token in the header of a request which your custom policy's requirement handler would have access to without the need for explicit parameters.

Your requirement's requirement handler to be used by your custom policy would look something like this

```
public class TokenHandler : AuthorizationHandler<TokenRequirement>
{
    //Some kind of token validator logic injected into your handler via DI
    private readonly TokenValidator _tokenValidator;

    //The http context of this request session also injected via DI
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpCtx;

    //The name of the header your token can be found under on a Http Request
    private const string tokenHeaderKey = "authToken";

    //Constructor using DI to get a instance of a TokenValidator class you would
    //have written yourself, and the httpContext
    public TokenHandler(TokenValidator tokenValidator, IHttpContextAccessor httpCtx)
    {
        _tokenValidator = tokenValidator;
        _httpCtx = httpCtx;
    }

    //Overriden implementation of base class AuthorizationHandler's HandleRequirementAsync method 
    //This is where you check your token.
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context
        ,TokenRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (context.Resource is Endpoint endpoint)
        {
            HttpRequest httpReqCtx = _httpCtx.HttpContext.Request;
            string token =
                httpReqCtx.Headers.TryGetValue(tokenHeaderKey, out StringValues tokenVal)
                    ? tokenVal.FirstOrDefault()
                    : null;

            if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(token))
            {
                context.Fail();
            }
            else
            {
                bool tokenIsValid = await _tokenValidator.ValidToken(token);
                if(tokenIsValid)
                    context.Succeed(requirement);
                else
                    context.Fail();
            }
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

You'd register your custom requirement handler on a custom policy name in Startup.cs like so

```
//This is a framework extension method under Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

//Your custom handler
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, TokenHandler>();

//Your custom policy
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(
        //Your custom policy's name, can be whatever you want
        "myCustomTokenCheckerPolicy",
        //The requirement your policy is going to check
        //Which will be handled by the req handler added above
        policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new TokenRequirement())
    );
});
```

The impl on the attribute would look like this

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("index")]
[Authorize(Policy = "myCustomTokenCheckerPolicy")]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: many thanks for this great answer. I've tried to follow your directions but the AuthorizationHandlerContext context of HandleRequirementAsync function has no value at all so token string always return null. I don't know why. Do you have any solutions?

Comment: Doing some quick googling it looks like things have changed slightly for .Net Core 3, sorry for the confusion. I'll update my answer to accurately reflect the changes needed for .Net Core 3.

Comment: Just updated, sorry it took a second. Also, here is the SO post I found that elaborated on the difference in implementation for .NET Core 3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60417327/2293177

Comment: I think maybe due to the TokenRequirement, I don't know why but the token string of HandleRequirementAsync always return null, thank you so much for help!

Comment: A couple things could cause that. I'd first check that you're actually passing the token as a header on your http request. Second, if you implemented my code to the letter, the header key I used may not match your own.

Headers are key-value pairs, they usually look like { "apiToken": "1234-abcd" } "apiToken" is the key and "1234-abcd" is the value.

If you try to get the token by searching for a header with a name of, "authToken" against my example you'd get null, b/c the token is under the name, "apiToken" in this instance.

So I'd check that you're using the correct request header key

Comment: May I miss client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization? I've tried to add it into my code, but it doesn't help anything

Comment: If you're adding your token in that way you should find its value under a key titled, "authorization". I would recommend trying to inspect the HttpRequest obj your handler is working with when you are trying to retrieve the header. You should be able to see a list of all the headers on the HttpRequest obj. You'll need to make sure the key matches exactly in the line httpReqCtx.Headers.TryGetValue(tokenHeaderKey, out StringValues tokenVal). So if tokenHeaderKey was, "Authorization" w/ a capital, "A" but the header key is "authorization", all lower-case your token variable will be set to null.

Comment: Could you possibly update your question to include the code you're using to set the token you're generating on the http request you're making to your server-side code? Also I'd recommend checking your HttpRequest obj's list of headers in your requirement handler. Right below HttpRequest httpReqCtx = _httpCtx.HttpContext.Request; in your requirement handler, just add this temporary line, var reqHeaders = httpReqCtx.Headers.ToList(); and then while debugging inspect the variable's values to identify if your token is showing up in the headers of the request your making from your client-side.